# Color ramp gradient 'flattened out'

Tags: node-editor

I'm experimenting with some procedural ways to create dunes, but I'm experiencing some issues with the color ramp. I want the top to be (close to) pefeclty sharp, but right now it is sort of beveled. Is this a limitation/issue with the color ramp and is there any way I can get rid of it?

[image: Render of Dune]
[image: Dune Nodes]

Comment: I would guess it's because your lighter value is clipping past the maximum "white". Try lowering the value somewhere in your node setup.